# implement devise recoverable and confirmable on non devise user login setup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I have custom functionalities developed for user's login and oauth login and now i wanted to add options for Forgotten Password (reset user's password) and confirm email (including send confirmation email).

Is it possible to add those devise features without rebuilding my whole user model and sessions controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: [Yes it's possible](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Add-:confirmable-to-Users).

Longer answer:

Here's how you can introduce confirmable to users while also marking existing users as confirmed.

add this to your users model.

```
devise :registerable, **:confirmable**
```

Then, do the migration as:
( in your terminal)

```
rails g migration add_confirmable_to_devise
```

**Your new migration:**

```
class AddConfirmableToDevise < ActiveRecord::Migration
  # Note: You can't use change, as User.update_all with fail in the down migration
  def self.up
    add_column :users, :confirmation_token, :string
    add_column :users, :confirmed_at, :datetime
    add_column :users, :confirmation_sent_at, :datetime
    # add_column :users, :unconfirmed_email, :string # Only if using reconfirmable
    add_index :users, :confirmation_token, :unique => true
    # User.reset_column_information # Need for some types of updates, but not for update_all.
    # To avoid a short time window between running the migration and updating all existing
    # users as confirmed, do the following
    User.update_all(:confirmed_at => Time.now)
    # All existing user accounts should be able to log in after this.
  end

  def self.down
    remove_columns :users, :confirmation_token, :confirmed_at, :confirmation_sent_at
    # remove_columns :users, :unconfirmed_email # Only if using reconfirmable
  end
end
```

If not using reconfirmable, update the configuration in config/initializers/devise.rb

```
config.reconfirmable = false
```

**In your Terminal:**

```
rails generate devise:views confirmable
rake db:migrate
```

Notes:

1. I had the same issue and did it the same way. I'm just copy pasting from the source.
2. If you got any further issues your first source [should be the devise How to page with over 9000 tutorials](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-Tos)